# Leer archivo Unicode en C++

Tags: c++

llevo un buen rato tratando de resolver este problema que tengo, pero no lo logro ni con ayuda de los foros...

**Quiero leer un archivo con caracteres Unicode para convertir los caracteres en números** (en ves de necesitar 6 ciclos para leer un numero de 6 dígitos, solo necesitaría 1 y luego convertirlo a Int). Pero no logro hacer un codigo que logre leer un archivo con la variable "wchar_t" (char = 1byte, wchar_t = 4bytes). Con este codigo puedo leer "char"s que van del 0-255, pero quiero expandirlo con "wchar_t"... (el contenido del archivo "ejemplo.hd" no importa en este ejemplo, solo son caracteres que al final serán convertidos a números)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
   std::string archivo("ejemplo.hd");
   std::vector<char> bytes;
   char byte = 0;

   std::ifstream input_file(archivo);
   if (!input_file.is_open()) {
       std::cout << "No se encontro el archivo - '"
           << archivo << "'\n";
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   while (input_file.get(byte)) {
       bytes.push_back(byte);
   }
   for (const auto& i : bytes) {
       std::cout << (int)i;
   }

   std::cout << '\n';
   input_file.close();

   return 0;}
```

Intente varias cosas con el std::wifstream, pero no me funciono (no se si lo implemente incorrectamente o no sirve para eso).
Les agradecería si pudieran ayudarme porfavor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para leer un archivo en UNICODE tenemos que abrirlo y leerlo como binario e ir leyendo de dos en dos bytes. Los dos bytes  los agregamos  a un wstring hasta que  lleguemos al caracter de fin de linea  (lo que vendria a ser el `\n`).  Al llegar  al fin de  linea  pasamos  `wstream` a un `string` normal (aqui puedes llevar este string a un vector que vaya guardando las lineas  leidas). Luego inicializamos nuestro `wstring` para empezar con la  linea siguiente. Al llegar al fin de linea tenemos  que  avanzar  2 bytes  adicionales  para  saltar el caracter de fin de linea.

Aqui te dejo como sería:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    std::string ws2s(const std::wstring& ws)
    {

        std::string curLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "chs");
     const wchar_t* _Source = ws.c_str();
     size_t _Dsize = 2 * ws.size() + 1;
     char *_Dest = new char[_Dsize];
     memset(_Dest, 0, _Dsize);
     wcstombs(_Dest, _Source, _Dsize);
     std::string result = _Dest;
     delete[]_Dest;
     setlocale(LC_ALL, curLocale.c_str());
     return result;
    }
    int main() {

        std::string archivo("ejemplo.hd");
        ifstream input_file;
        input_file.open(archivo, ios::binary);
        if (!input_file.is_open())
        {
            cout << "No se pudo abrir archivo." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        vector<string> registros;
        size_t pos = 2;
        wstring linea;
        int nLinea = 0;
        while (!input_file.eof())
        {
            input_file.seekg(pos, ios::beg);
            wchar_t wch;
            input_file.read((char*)(&wch), 2);
            if (wch == 0x000D) // fin de  linea  
            {
                string strLinea = ws2s(linea);  // convertimos a str                
                registros.push_back(strLinea);
                linea.erase(0, linea.size() + 1);  // borramos nuestra  linea unicod
                nLinea++; // siguiente  linea 
                pos += 4; // saltamos el fin de linea 
            }
            else
            {
                linea.append(1, wch);
                pos += 2;
            }
        }
        string strLinea = ws2s(linea);  // convertimos a str                  
        registros.push_back(strlinea);
        for (auto s = registros.begin(); s != registros.end(); s++) {
             cout << *s << endl; 
        }

        return  0;


    }
```

*ACTUALIZACION*

Te dejo algunas rutinas para leer archivos UTF16  y UTF32. Por si acaso aquellos caracteres extendidos  no van a visualizarse por la consola pero  internamente si se leen. Te lo dejo a manera de ejemplo. El bloque UTF16LE hace  lo mismo que la rutina que puse  arriba. Todas las rutinas  leen de caracter e n caracter. La variable wch o wc según sea el caso es la que puedes convertirla a entero  (aunque ya son enteros realmente).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <vector>

using  namespace std;

enum {
        UTF16_LE,
        UTF16_BE,
        UTF32_LE,
        UTF32_BE,
};

int  GetEncoding(string archivo) {
    std::ifstream input_file(archivo, ifstream::binary);

    if (!input_file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "No se pudo abrir archivo." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    unsigned char byte[4] = { 0 };
    input_file.read((char*)byte, 4);
    input_file.close();
    if (byte[0] == 0xff && byte[1] == 0xfe && byte[2] == 0x00 && byte[3] == 0) return UTF32_LE;
        if (byte[0] == 0x00 && byte[1] == 0x00 && byte[2] == 0xfe && byte[3] == 0xff) return UTF32_BE;
        if (byte[0] == 0xff && byte[1] == 0xfe) return UTF16_LE;
        if (byte[0] == 0xfe && byte[1] == 0xff) return UTF16_BE;

    return -1;
   }


int  main() {
    
        std::string archivo("c:\\apps\\utf16le");
    //  std::string archivo("c:\\apps\\utf16be");
    //  std::string archivo("c:\\apps\\utf32le");
    //  std::string archivo("c:\\apps\\utf32be");

        int  fileEncoding = GetEncoding(archivo);

        switch (fileEncoding)
        {

        case UTF16_LE:
        {

            std::ifstream input_file(archivo);
            input_file.imbue(std::locale(input_file.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, little_endian>));
            wchar_t wch;
            wcout.imbue(std::locale(input_file.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
            wstring  linea;
            vector<wstring>  lineas;
            input_file.read((char*)&wch, sizeof(wch));
            while (!input_file.eof())
            {
                input_file.read((char*)&wch, sizeof(wch));

                if (wch == L'\n' || wch == L'\r') {
                    lineas.push_back(linea);
                    linea.clear();
                }
                else {
                    linea.append(1, wch);
                }
            }

            _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

            for (auto s : lineas) {
                wprintf(L"%s\n", s.c_str());
            }

            input_file.close();

        }
        break;

        case UTF16_BE:
        {
            std::ifstream input_file(archivo);
            input_file.imbue(std::locale(input_file.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>));
            wchar_t wch;
            wcout.imbue(std::locale(input_file.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
            wstring  linea;
            vector<wstring>  lineas;
            input_file.read((char*)&wch, sizeof(wch));
            wchar_t wc = (wchar_t)(((wchar_t)((wch & 0xFF00) >> 8)) | ((wchar_t)((wch << 8) & 0xFF00)));
            while (!input_file.eof())
            {
                input_file.read((char*)&wch, sizeof(wch));
                wchar_t wc = (wchar_t)(((wchar_t)((wch & 0xFF00) >> 8)) | ((wchar_t)((wch << 8) & 0xFF00)));

                if (wc == 0x000a || wc == 0x000d) {
                    lineas.push_back(linea);
                    linea.clear();
                }
                else {
                    linea.append(1, wc);
                }
            }

            for (auto s : lineas) {
                wcout << s.c_str() << endl;
            }
        }
        break;

        case UTF32_BE:
        {
            char32_t wch = U'0';
            std::ifstream input_file(archivo, ifstream::binary);
            if (!input_file.is_open())
            {
                cout << "No se pudo abrir archivo." << endl;
                return 0;
            }
            input_file.read((char*)&wch, 4);
            u32string  l32;
//          wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv;
            wcout.imbue(std::locale(input_file.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
            vector<u32string>  lineas;
            while (!input_file.eof())
            {
                input_file.read((char*)&wch, sizeof(wch));
                wchar_t wc1 = (wchar_t)((wch & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
                wchar_t wc2 = (wchar_t)(wch & 0x0000FFFF);

                wc1 = (wchar_t)(((wchar_t)((wc1 & 0xFF00) >> 8)) | ((wchar_t)((wc1 << 8) & 0xFF00)));

                wc2 = (wchar_t)(((wchar_t)((wc2 & 0xFF00) >> 8)) | ((wchar_t)((wc2 << 8) & 0xFF00)));


                char32_t wc = (char32_t)(wc2 | wc1);
                if (wc == U'\n' || wc == U'\r') {
                    lineas.push_back(l32);
                    l32.clear();
                }
                else {
                    l32.append(1, wc);
                }
            }

            for (auto s : lineas) {
                for (auto c : s) {
                    wcout << (wchar_t*)&c;
                }
                wcout << endl;
            }
            
            input_file.close();
        }
        break;

        case UTF32_LE:
        {
            char32_t wch = U'0';
            std::ifstream input_file(archivo, ifstream::binary);
            if (!input_file.is_open())
            {
                cout << "No se pudo abrir archivo." << endl;
                return 0;
            }

            input_file.read((char*)&wch, 4);
            u32string  l32;
    //      wstring_convert<codecvt<wchar_t,char,mbstate_t>> conv;

            vector<u32string>  lineas;

            while (!input_file.eof())
            {
                input_file.read((char*)&wch, sizeof(wch));


                if (wch == U'\n') {
                    lineas.push_back(l32);
                    l32.clear();
                }
                else {
                    l32.append(1, wch);
                }
            }
            for (auto s : lineas) {
                for (auto c : s) {
                    wcout << (wchar_t*)&c;
                }
                wcout << endl;
            }

            input_file.close();
        }

        break;
        }



        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127486/discussion-on-answer-by-juan-carlos-guibovich-leer-archivo-unicode-en-c).